# Adding attributes to address points?

Tags: qgis

I am trying to manually add zoning info to my map by referencing pdfs. Can anyone tell me the best way to go about this?

There are 12,000 lots.

[image: qgis map of lots and address points and attributes table open]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Spatial Join tool?

Comment: Are you trying to add a column with zoning info? can you add an example of the pdf's? are they layered with geo-info? you may not need to do it manually if there is something that can be used from the pdf's.

Comment: I added an example of the zoning maps to the OP. They are just images. If I could figure out how to scale raster layers i could place them in the right spot, drop the opacity and use the selection tool to grab appropriate address points to batch edit.